# Where should I ask questions about which platform I should use?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Me and my colleagues are thinking about changing the framework of the project we're working on, and we couldn't decide among two frameworks, so I wanted to ask the community about the pros and cons of these two frameworks and their experiences.

But I was not sure on which community I should ask this question. Can someone point me to the right direction? I once tried to ask this kind of question on Stack Overflow but it got many downvotes saying this is not the right place to ask this kind of question.

Comment: I think the site called [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) is for this kind of questions.